# How can I prevent p:commandButton to refresh p:tabView

Tags: forms, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, jsf-1.2

my `xhtml` page has this format:

```
    <h:form>
      <p:dialog widgetVar="presentDiag" modal="true" closable="true" header="Liste" maximizable="false" dynamic="true">

            <p:commandButton value="Submit" id="submit" actionListener="bean.add()"/>
      </p:dialog>
    </h:form>
    <h:form>
       <p:tabView>
            <p:tab title="....">
            </p:tab>
            <p:tab title="....">
            </p:tab>
            <p:tab title="....">
           </p:tab>
           </p:tabView>
       </h:form>
```

when I click on the submit button the selected tab changed to the first tab

Comment: But as I can see that the submit button is not updating anything ? maybe forgot to mention it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wanted to update a form and then exclude something from it, the easiest way would be to use [PrimeFaces selectors](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/selectors.jsf) like so :

```
<h:form id="form">
  <p:dialog widgetVar="presentDiag" modal="true" closable="true" header="Liste" maximizable="false" dynamic="true">
        <p:commandButton value="Submit" id="submit" actionListener="bean.add()" update="@(form :not(.tab-view))"/>
  </p:dialog>
  <h:panelGroup styleClass="tab-view" >
       <p:tabView>
           <p:tab title="....">
           </p:tab>
           <p:tab title="....">
           </p:tab>
           <p:tab title="....">
           </p:tab>
       </p:tabView>
   </h:panelGroup>
 </h:form>
```

you can always reopen a desired tab by using `widgetVar` attribute.

```
<p:tabView widgetVar="myTab"> .... </p:tabView>
 .
 .
 .
 <p:commandButton value="Submit" id="submit" actionListener="bean.add()" update="someId" oncomplete="myTab.select(2);"/>
```

but the best thing to do would be not closing it in the first place.

Comment: then you should make your intentions more clear. In this case simply give your table ID and update only it.

Comment: as long as this `someId` is not around the `<p:tabView>`